# Flyway-maven-plugin how to read the settings from spring boot application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

In my Spring Boot project I want to use flyway-maven-plugin. 
My pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_unicode_ci&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And here is my application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles.active: default
---
spring:
  profiles: default
spring.datasource:
  password: root
```

As I understood to use `mvn flyway:info` I need some plugin which will read my application.yml. Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: Why would you want to use the plugin? Spring Boot takes care of executing flyway for you, no need to do that in your maven file.

Answer (score 5):

I have the following in my `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433
flyway.user=james_hetfield
flyway.password=MetaLLic@

spring.datasource.url=${flyway.url}
spring.datasource.user=${flyway.user}
spring.datasource.password=${flyway.password}
```

And then I run the migrations from the command-line as follows

```
mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=src/main/resources/application.properties flyway:migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that if you are using Flyway with Spring Boot you do not use the flyway-maven plugin.

**EDIT:**  Using Flyway CLI has a place when you need to work with the DB directly to make modifications to Flyway's schema table.  An example would be to `init` an existing DB or `clean` a test project.

These are the current settings that can be performed out of the box by setting properties within the `application.properties` for Flyway.

```
# FLYWAY (FlywayProperties)
flyway.check-location=false # check that migration scripts location exists
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration # locations of migrations scripts
flyway.schemas= # schemas to update
flyway.init-version= 1 # version to start migration
flyway.init-sqls= # SQL statements to execute to initialize a connection immediately after obtaining it
flyway.sql-migration-prefix=V
flyway.sql-migration-suffix=.sql
flyway.enabled=true
flyway.url= # JDBC url if you want Flyway to create its own DataSource
flyway.user= # JDBC username if you want Flyway to create its own DataSource
flyway.password= # JDBC password if you want Flyway to create its own DataSource
```

YAML version:

```
flyway:
    check-location: false
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    ....
```

If you need further customization you may need to write a `@Bean` to further customize how Flyway interacts with your application.

Comment: There is not possible to run 'info, validate, repair' and other functions not using CLI or maven plugin. Also I'm not using application.properties. I have application.yml.

Comment: You are correct, unless you modify the config of Spring Boot.  Thinking about the workflow to `init` an existing DB.  The Flyway CLI would be great.  Then let Spring Boot handle the migrations.

Comment: YAML is supported for Flyway in Spring Boot.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about how to use Flyway in yaml

Answer (score 1):

To read `*.yml` properties from pom you should use https://github.com/aadnk/yaml-properties-plugin